# Convert boolean field to custom style

Tags: 8, entities, theming

I have a **`Boolean`** field with **`Yes/No`** values with default style of Drupal .

[image]

I want to change that field to **`ON`** and **`OFF`** toggle style like below .

[image]

I understand that it can be done using the **`bootstrap`** theme and the [bootstrap toggle](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_toggle) module. But I don't need to change my theme. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the bootstrap toggle JavaScript code does not show any actual dependencies in it for the actual bootstrap theme.  You may be able to install the bootstrap_toggle module without the Bootstrap theme and it will work.

Won't hurt to try on a dev environment. :)

Comment: When enabled the `bootstrap_toggle module` the functionality is working , but no style . Again when i included the `bootstrap.min.css` the style for on and off toggle is coming , but its breaking styles in some pages (as its affecting bootstrap style for all elements i guess ;( ) .Yea i have to manually style the on and off toggles is the solution i guess .

Comment: Hmm, looking at the bootstrap-toggle.css, I only see CSS specifiers that have the  .toggle identifier.  Can't see how that would effect other styles.  It might be a bootstrap template difference.  You may be able to fix this by getting the related template from the bootstrap theme and adding it to your theme with a name that limits it to your field type. (e.g. look at the template debuging suggestions).  May be easier than restyling.